# How do I remove this wall mount faucet nut?

Tags: faucet, removal, kitchen-sink

I have no problems pulling the single handle two-hole Moen wall mount faucet out, but this part is left behind. I can not for the life of me figure out how to remove it. It spins freely in both directions, which I guess makes sense because tightening/loosening it is how the fixture is attached. I need it gone so I can attach a new fixture. I can't find a set screw on it or anything that seems to be holding it in place. Help?

[image: Faucet mounting nut]

[image: Front facing view]

Comment: Can you include a picture looking straight into the faucet nut?

Comment: Is it screwed into the brass fitting that just pokes out of the wall?  That would make sense given the flat sides on the threaded part that would allow a pair of pliers or a wrench to get in there.

Comment: Photo added, and yes, it's screwed on to the brass poking out.

Comment: Does it move back and forth/out a bit?  Just wondering if it is like a compression nut that allows you to tighten it when the pipe/hose can't turn.  I had them on hydraulic hoses.

Comment: Nope. It's pretty fixed in place.

Comment: Did you put one wrench on the brass fitting and another on the silver to attempt to unscrew the silver piece?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is a lock ring of any sort in that fitting so it might be easiest to remove the brass reducer it's connected to by turning it with a pipe wrench counterclockwise and then getting the new fittinge based on what you're replacing it with.

Comment: Be careful when attempting to unscrew the brass part to ensure that you're unscrewing it, not something further into the wall.